# How must I define a color array property in a Shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

I have seen that you can set a color array in a material from Unity3D, using this method:

**[Material.SetColorArray](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColorArray.html)**

***Sets a color array property on the material**. If a color array property with the given name already exists, the old value is replaced.
The array length can't be changed once it has been added to the block. If you subsequently try to set a longer array into the same property, the length will be capped to the original length and the extra items you tried to assign will be ignored. If you set a shorter array than the original length, your values will be assigned but the original values will remain for the array elements beyond the length of your new shorter array.*

The problem comes when I try to find how to define those properties like the next:

```
Properties
{
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    **_Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)**
    [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
}
```

I have tried something like:

```
_Color ("Tint", Color[]) = []
```

But of course it isn't working. I have no idea of how to define them.

**P.S: I understand how to define them into the CGPROGRAM part, but we are talking about properties.**

Thank you for your time.